# SQL Server Drop Table Error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to drop by temp table if it exists, but I'm getting the error below. I've used this method with tables in the past, I'm not sure why its not working in this case.

SQL

```
Create table mytable(col_a int)

insert into mytable
values(1)

IF object_id(#temp, 'U') IS NOT NULL 
   drop table #temp

select * 
into #temp 
from dbo.mytable
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Invalid column name '#temp'.

Comment: I am not sure scenario where you want to drop `temp` table, believe me your problem is not to drop `temp` table but need to find why you want to drop it, since `sql server` automatically handle it once scope has ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For visitors from the future (hello!) on SQL Server 2016

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a temp table, not a physical table. Try this.

```
Create table mytable(col_a int)
insert into mytable
values(1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
Select * into #temp from dbo.mytable
```